# Swing JWebBrowser issue - SocketException

Tags: java, swing, socketexception, jwebbrowser

I made a swing  app that integrates a `JWebBrowser`. It worked fine and it still does when run from NetBeans but suddenly when I ran it from dist folder-execution folder it gives me:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:java.net.SocketException:Connection reset
```

This is the same message I got when I tried to run my Windows made java app in Ubuntu . How is that I am suddenly getting this error - exception and I was not getting it before when I was running my application?

What I did recently is that I installed Mozilla Java plugin - I thought this was the issue since `JWebBrowser`  uses Mozilla engine , but I deactivated Java Mozilla plugin and my app will not show the browser it shows it only when I  run it from NetBeans . What is this all about?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that that problem was in the lower level of java installed on pc I was running my app .